# Importing MsalModule which does not have a ɵmod property

Tags: angular, ts-jest, msal-angular

I've recently upgraded from Angular 12 to 13, which broke the Jest test for AppComponent, with the errors centring on MSAL. I updated @azure/msal-angular and @azure/msal-browser to their latest v2 packages, but this made no difference. I looked up the angular13-rxjs7-sample-app and aligned my app.component.spec.ts with that of the sample app - this helped to solve the initial error I was facing (NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for MsalService: (?, ?).) but has thrown (Importing MsalModule which does not have a ɵmod property) instead, and this error I can't resolve.

```
  Importing MsalModule which does not have a ɵmod property

  10 |   beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
> 11|     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     |             ^
  12|       imports: [
  13|         RouterTestingModule,
  14|         AppModule
```

Has anyone encountered this, and/or could shed some light on how I resolve this?

Here are my configuration details/relevant code:

- Core Library: @azure/msal-browser 2.37.0
- Wrapper Library: @azure/msal-angular 2.5.7
- MSAL Configuration

  ```
   { 
     auth: {
        clientId: {{ClientId}},
        authority: 'https://' + {{TenantId}} + '.b2clogin.com/' + {{TenantId}} + '.onmicrosoft.com/' + {{Policy}},
        knownAuthorities: [{{TenantId}} + '.b2clogin.com'],
        redirectUri: {{RedirectUri}},
        postLogoutRedirectUri: {{RedirectUri}},
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
       cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
       storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    }
  }
  ```
- app.component.spec.ts

  ```
   import { TestBed, waitForAsync, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
   import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { AppModule } from './app.module';

   describe('AppComponent', () => {
     let component: AppComponent;
     let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

     beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [
           RouterTestingModule,
           AppModule
         ],
         declarations: [
           AppComponent
         ]
       }).compileComponents();
     }));

     beforeEach(() => {
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;
       fixture.detectChanges();
     });

     it('should create the app', () => {
       const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
       const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
       expect(app).toBeTruthy();
     });
   });
  ```